# how to get input file name of a record in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am creating a dataframe in spark by loading tab separated files from s3. I need to get the input file name information of each record in the dataframe for further processing. I tried

```
dataframe.select(inputFileName())
```

But I am getting null value for input_file_name. somebody please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can create a new column on the data frame using `withColumn` and `input_file_name()`:

```
dataframe.withColumn("input_file", input_file_name())
```