# How to add filename as a column to a a Java RDD with Spark?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using apache Spark, we need to process a bunch of files and track which files have certain keywords in them.

I'm attempting to create a dataframe with two columns:

- line from a file
- file that contained the line

Here's what I have so far:

```
String[] sourceLogPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(getLogSourceDirectory())).filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(path -> path.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray((new String[0]));
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("LogSearcher").master("local").getOrCreate();

// sourceLogPaths is an array of different file names
JavaRDD<String> textFile = spark.read().textFile(sourceLogPaths).javaRDD();
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = textFile.map(RowFactory::create);
// How to add a field that shows the associated filename for each row?
List<StructField> fields = Arrays.asList(DataTypes.createStructField("line", DataTypes.StringType, true)); 
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
SQLContext sqlContext = spark.sqlContext();
Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

df.show();
```

Which prints out:

```
+--------------------+
|                line|
+--------------------+
|1331901000.000000...|
|1331901000.000000...|
|1331901000.000000...|
...
```

Can anyone help me understand how to get the original file's name added as a second column?

Searching for advice has led to advice [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970738/how-to-get-input-file-name-of-a-record-in-spark-dataframe), but I'm uncertain of how to translate that in this scenario.

Thanks in advance, I'm new to Spark and any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Not a java spark expert but I would like to give it a try. Can you do something like `spark.read().textFile(sourceLogPaths).withColumn("filename", input_file_name()).javaRDD();` ?

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I am not Java guy , but in python using spark you can provide the whole folder or patter of files and use something like this below.. if local file system use file: at the front. filename will add filename to the data.

```
df = spark.read.text('/datafolder/foldername/*')
df = df.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rafa I think this is the answer:

```
String[] sourceLogPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(getLogSourceDirectory())).filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(path -> path.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray((new String[0]));
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("LogSearcher").master("local").getOrCreate();

// sourceLogPaths is an array of different file names
JavaRDD<String> textFile = spark.read().textFile(sourceLogPaths).javaRDD();
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = textFile.map(RowFactory::create);
// How to add a field that shows the associated filename for each row?
List<StructField> fields = Arrays.asList(DataTypes.createStructField("line", DataTypes.StringType, true)); 
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
SQLContext sqlContext = spark.sqlContext();

// Below line has the additional column added
Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).withColumn("file_name", input_file_name());

df.show();
```

Prints

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                line|           file_name|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|1331901000.000000...|file:///Users/acu...|
|1331901000.000000...|file:///Users/acu...|
|1331901000.000000...|file:///Users/acu...|
|1331901000.010000...|file:///Users/acu...|
```